# Forest linguistics tree sideways/rotated

Tags: rotating, forest, linguistics

I've been searching around now to see if I could find a solution for this, without any luck. Hence, I ask the question to you.

I am using Lyx with the Linguistics module, and I want to basically make a simple binomial tree, with the Starting note in the middle, and the branches going out to the right. Similar to this:

[image: Binomial tree]
An example of the simple code just currently looks like, written inside the custom inset, Structure tree:

```
[50 [60][40] ]
```

But that just gives me the three pointing downwards/south. How to I make the branches go out to the right/east?

Best,
Anders

Comment: Please provide a complete example. Preferably, code for a small `.tex` document we can use to reproduce the issue. Failing that, a small `.lyx` document. If you post `.tex` more people can help.  Are you using `forest`? You've tagged it, but don't say. If you're using Forest, put `for tree={grow'=0}` in the tree's preamble i.e. before the first square bracket.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using `forest`? You've tagged it, but don't say. If you're using Forest, put `for tree={grow'=0}` in the tree's preamble i.e. before the first square bracket.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=0}
  [ A 
    [ B ]
    [ C ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: growing East]